# Como usar BackGroundWorker con timer para cancelar un proceso C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, backgroundworker

Buenas noches tengo una consulta. Quisiera usar el backgroundworker en mi aplicación, pero no tengo ni idea como realizarlo. Mi aplicación toma bastante tiempo en realizar ciertas validaciones, mientras esto se realiza, esta queda congelada. La idea que tengo es colocar un botón CANCELAR o FINALIZAR. ¿Como pudiera realizarlo?. Este es mi código, aquí se realiza todo el proceso.

Empecé uno de 0 tipo simulación este esta en un timer porque debe de realizarse cada cierto tiempo.

Se inicia el procedimiento

```
public Formulario()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
Ocupo mi boton de iniciar el proceso





   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                // Start the asynchronous operation.
                
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                timer1.Start();
            }
        }
    
     - private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                   {
                       if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
                       {
                           // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
                           backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
                       }
                   }
```

Y aqui se encuentra mi proceso que esta enlazado con una base de datos que hara la insercion de varios registros , pero igual como mencione se queda pasmado al entrar a realizar este proceso.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 180000;

            using (ServiceReference1.ServiceClient wsRPA_Invesdoc = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient())
            {
                DateTime ldatFechaActual = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime ldatFechaAnterior = ldatFechaActual.AddDays(-1);

                string lstrFechaRegistro1 = ldatFechaAnterior.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                string lstrFechaRegistro2 = ldatFechaAnterior.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

                string lstrInvesdoc = wsRPA_Invesdoc.plistObtenerGuiasInvesdoc(lstrFechaRegistro1, lstrFechaRegistro2);
                int columnas = gdvRegistros.Rows.Add();
                gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[0].Value = ldatFechaActual.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[1].Value = ldatFechaAnterior.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[2].Value = lstrInvesdoc.ToString();

            }
        }

Y intente hacer esto con el back pero no le entendi mucho porque no me deja cancelar aun asi , no se que este haciendo mal.
```

// This event handler is where the time-consuming work is done.
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
//BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;

            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 10);
        }
    }
}

// This event handler updates the progress.
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // resultLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

    if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
    }
}

// This event handler deals with the results of the background operation.
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("cancelado");
        resultLabel.Text = "Canceled!";
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ocurrio un error ");
        resultLabel.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("se termino");
        resultLabel.Text = "Done!";
    }
}
```

Comment: He visto varias preguntas tuyas relacionadas con lo mismo, casi todas sin respuestas lo que te debería dar una pista de que algo estás haciendo mal con tus preguntas y lo peor de todo es que estas preguntando algo muy sencillo, pero tu código es tan ilegible que no hay como ayudarte.

Comment: Por otro lado tú tienes un barra de progreso, hay de 2 tipos: 1) Indeterminadas: Son básicamente una animación que indica movimiento, pero no alerta al usuario de cuanto falta para que el proceso termine,  y se ocupan cuando no se sabe cuántos "pasos" tiene el proceso. 2) Determinadas, es el caso contrario. Se sabe cuántos pasos existen, entonces es posible mostrar una barra que sea proporcional a las tareas ejecutadas. Tú sabes de antemano cuantos pasos realiza tu proceso??

Comment: en realidad he hecho pero con diferentes temas, agradezco sus comentarios. E igual he leido otras preguntas explicadas igual que la mia y he ido tomando notas de como preguntan estas personas que tienen respuestas.  Y si,  es un proceso que se ocupa en dos  partes una que se ejecuta a cierta hora y otra que da a elegir fechas . Nuevamente agradezco el comentario.

Comment: si supongo que es un tema sencillo , pero yo desconozco del tema es la primera vez que lo veo y por eso mi confusión. Y las contestaciones que me dan luego otros comentan que no son correctas para el proceso que tengo.